# Htacces not redirect when same words on the front

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have code htacces like this:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^location-jakarta(.*) location-jakarta.php
RewriteRule ^location-jakarta-south(.*) location-jakarta-south.php
RewriteRule ^location-jakarta-north(.*) location-jakarta-north.php

ErrorDocument 404 /home
</IfModule>
```

If I go to `domain.com/location-jakarta` it's ok!.
but, if I go to `domain.com/location-jakarta-south` or `domain.com/location-jakarta-north` it's redirect to `domain.com/location-jakarta` . how to solve that? thanks

EDIT: 
and I added mod_expires.c like this

```html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hours"
# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 hours"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 hours"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 hours"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 hours"
# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 hours"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 hours"
# Fonts
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 hours"
#spesifik file
<Files ~ "^(style\.css)$">
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 5 seconds"
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have been tried in localhost with `put RewriteRule ^location-jakarta(.*) location-jakarta.php at last`. but it same. other idea?

Answer (score 0):

i have been a solve. i added /?$ after `RewriteRule ^location-jakarta(.*) location-jakarta.php` to `RewriteRule ^location-jakarta/?$ location-jakarta.php` check -> [htaccess similar file names goes to same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964172/htaccess-similar-file-names-goes-to-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rules depend on order so your first rewrite rule is grabbing ALL requests even to the north/south pages.

Try reordering...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^location-jakarta-south(.*) location-jakarta-south.php
RewriteRule ^location-jakarta-north(.*) location-jakarta-north.php
RewriteRule ^location-jakarta(.*) location-jakarta.php

ErrorDocument 404 /home
</IfModule>
```